# How to restart nginx web server on ubuntu without getting error?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nginx-location

I used many tips from stack to restart nginx but i get error. Wenn i use this:

```
service nginx start
```

I get this error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Some like whit this:  `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

with `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload`:

```
nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Any hope to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried doing "journalctl -xe" like it says in the error?

Comment: yes, it returnes many error:   https://jsfiddle.net/g1fm8ae4/.

Comment: Can you maybe edit the answer to show more of your config? Like the test2 worker?